# Не отображается блок по центру при изменении размера окна

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, разметка

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при изменении размера окна, все колонки отлично становятся в центр, изменяя при том свое число в ряду, а вот заголовок (обернут в div) не становится по центру при размере xs (<= 576px). margin auto не помогает.

```css
{
 font-family: "Tahoma";
}

.container {
 width: 1200px;
 margin-bottom: 97px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.section-title {
 margin-top: 70px;
 margin-bottom: 82px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.image {
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 80px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.text {
 min-height: 34px;
 min-width: 160px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <h1 class="section-title">
      Почему нужно сделать это сейчас?
    </h1>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-2">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="img/img_1.png" alt="Image 1">
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            Первое преимущество
          </div>
        </div>


         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-2">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="img/img_2.png" alt="Image 2">
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            Второе преимущество
          </div>
        </div>


         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-2">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="img/img_3.png" alt="Image 3">
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            Третье преимущество
          </div>
        </div>


         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-2">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="img/img_4.png" alt="Image 4">
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            Четвертое преимущество
          </div>
        </div>


         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-2">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="img/img_5.png" alt="Image 5">
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            Пятое преимущество
          </div>
        </div>


         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-2">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="img/img_6.png" alt="Image 6">
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            Шестое преимущество
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выпишите `заголовок обернут в div`, а в коде он без всякого дива... В Вашем примере размер body - 512px, а размер контейнера с картинками  1200. В этом примере картинки не по центру, а за экраном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="section-title">
            Почему нужно сделать это сейчас?
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, осознал свой косяк, такой простейший) в Вашем же кусочке кода, я поменял row и section-title местами, иначе блоки "залазят" наверх, справа от заголовка при обычной ширине экрана. После изменения все заработало как надо, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @Andelight https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers